# Как получить value в form из input?

Tags: javascript

Хочу подставить вместо "ЗНАЧЕНИЕ" текст из инпута text. Как такое делается?

```
<form class="search" method="post" action=".../ЗНАЧЕНИЕ">
    <input type="text" name="text" ну и тут всякое>
    <input type="submit" value="Найти" class="button">
</form>
```

Comment: Это не так работает. При сабмите формы значение input улетает на action где его можно найти в post данных. Зачем вам менять атрибут?

Comment: @InDevX  Мне надо ссылку изменить изменить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML:

```xml
<form class="search" method="post" action=".../ЗНАЧЕНИЕ">
    <input id="ho-ho" type="text" name="text">
    <input type="submit" value="Найти" class="button">
</form>
```

JS:

```js
var inp = document.querySelector('#ho-ho');
var frm = document.querySelector('.search');
inp.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  frm.action = inp.value;
});
```

Тест: https://jsfiddle.net/a7nydt62/

**P.S.** - Скрипт надо добавлять после формы, иначе он выполнится еще до того как браузер догрузит необходимые элементы.

```xml
<html>
  <body>
    <form class="search" method="post" action=".../ЗНАЧЕНИЕ">
      <input id="ho-ho" type="text" name="text">
      <input type="submit" value="Найти" class="button">
    </form>
    <script>
       var inp = document.querySelector('#ho-ho');
       var frm = document.querySelector('.search');
       inp.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
         frm.action = inp.value;
       });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Это, конечно, прикольно, но нельзя ли как-то изящнее сделать, чтобы внутри action была приписка или что-то подобное?

Comment: Думаю, что нельзя. Любые изменения на юае отслеживаются ивент листенерами. По другому невозможно узнать появились ли в инпуте какие-то значения и присвоить их куда-то.

Comment: Стоп, а ваш скрит ведь не изменяет action

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: Посмотрите тест. Откройте девтулы и проверьте.

Comment: Тест я вижу, но, как посмотреть изменение ссылки, я не знаю. 
Может я js неправильно пишу? Я его просто в head поместил

Comment: Смотрите обновление в ответе

Comment: Спасибо) Только вот почему-то последний символ не отображается

Comment: Смотрите обновление в ответе: замена `keypress` на `change`

Comment: Огромное спасибо за помощь!